# Access INSERTで文字列をセットするときに、全角スペースが半角スペースとして見られてしまう

Tags: sql, ms-access

お世話になります。

MicroSoft Access2010で、ある特定のフォルダの配下のすべてのファイルを調べ、
そのファイルのフルパスをキーとして登録するコードをC#で書いています。
ファイルのフルパスでは、きちんと半角スペースと全角スペースは別物として
判断してあるのに、Accessに登録しようとすると、文字列の中に全角スペースが
あっても、半角スペースとして登録(INSERT)しようとしてしまい、すでに
登録済みとしてキー違反になってしまいます。

テキストモードとバイナリモードというのがあるのは解ったのですが、INSERTするときに
バイナリモードでできればよいとは思うのですが…。

半角と全角をきちんと識別して扱う方法を教えてください。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

何らかの方法でエンコードした状態でテーブルに格納し、その値を利用するときはデコードしてから利用する、というのはどうでしょうか。

---

例えば、一般的に「URLエンコード」と呼ばれる方法を採用するとします。
以下の2種類のパスを格納する場合を考えます。

```
"C:\Path 1" ... 半角空白で区切られている
"C:\Path　1" ... 全角空白で区切られている
```

UTF-8でURLエンコードした場合、各パスは以下のように表され、区別できます。

```
"C%3A%5CPath%201"
"C%3A%5CPath%E3%80%801"
```

---

エンコードの方法は、別にURLエンコードでなくてもかまいません。
仮に半角/全角空白が区別できればよい＆それ以外の文字はASCII文字しかない、ということなら、もっとシンプルなオレオレエンコード（例えば半角空白を"★"に置き換える、など）でもよいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。結局のところ、事前に何らかの手を加えてから…ということしかなさそうですね。ぜひ、URLエンコードを試してみたいと思います(文字数は増えてしまいますが^^;)。ファイル名を扱うので、不特定多数の文字が使われるので、オレオレはできなさそうです…。今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

うろ覚えですが、Accessでは空白に限らず全角・半角を区別しないはずです。それ以外にも「ファイル名」と「テキスト」（の一意制約）とでは区別するルールが異なるため、ファイル名をテキストで扱うこと自体に無理があります。

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。確かに、ご指摘の通りのようです。その為の対処法のようなものはないのでしょうか？

Comment: 対処法はなくて、テーブル設計を見直すほかないと思います。